# displaying different records depending on the parent tab clicked django

Tags: django, tabs

I have two tabs :

- my parent tab contains a list of cars
- my child tab contains car details, performance, offers

I am trying to display different data depending on which of the parent tabs is displayed.

**Expected results :**

```
parent tab

car one | car two 


child tab 

car details | performance | offers
```

results display here

**tabs.html**

```
<!-- parent tab -->

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {% for car in cars %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
        <li class="active"><a href="#carDetails" data-toggle="tab">{{car.name}}</a></li>
        {%else%}
        <li><a href="#carDetails" data-toggle="tab">{{car.name}}</a></li>
        {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>

<!-- child tab -->

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#carDetails" data-toggle="tab">Car Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#performance" data-toggle="tab">Performance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#offers" data-toggle="tab">Offers</a></li>
    </ul>

<!-- for loop -->

{% for car in cars.id %}
    <tr>
        <td class=" vertical-center">
            <a href="">{{ car.name }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

All cars detail tabs should put in the html, and the first tab defaults  visible, the others defaults hidden. You change tab to display by Javascript.